# Elasticsearch snapshots in Kubernetes not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup Elasticsearch snapshots for a Kubernetes cluster running in Google Cloud Platform.

I have done the following:

- Setup a service account with storage admin permission
- Generated a key for the service account stored in a json file.
- Created a new storage bucket and gave the newly created service account the following permissions to the storage bucket: storage.admin, object.creation and others.
- I did an exec into the elasticsearch pod and added the json file key using the command `elasticsearch-keystore add-file gcs.client.default.credentials_file /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic_snapshot.json`
- I visited the kibana UI and tried to add the GCP storage bucket as a repository for snapshots
- Afterwhich I tried to verify the repository, but I got this error:

[image]

```
  {
  "name": "ResponseError",
  "meta": {
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "repository_verification_exception",
            "reason": "[elasticsearch-snapshots-new] path  is not accessible on master node"
          }
        ],
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[elasticsearch-snapshots-new] path  is not accessible on master node",
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "storage_exception",
          "reason": "403 Forbidden\nPOST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/elasticsearch-snapshots-new/o?ifGenerationMatch=0&projection=full&uploadType=multipart\n{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 403,\n    \"message\": \"Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"forbidden\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "google_json_response_exception",
            "reason": "403 Forbidden\nPOST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/elasticsearch-snapshots-new/o?ifGenerationMatch=0&projection=full&uploadType=multipart\n{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 403,\n    \"message\": \"Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"forbidden\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n"
          }
        }
      },
      "status": 500
    },
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {
      "x-opaque-id": "57a97e1d-1ac4-4fab-9b27-c69aceea0ecf",
      "x-elastic-product": "Elasticsearch",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "content-length": "1874"
    },
    "meta": {
      "context": null,
      "request": {
        "params": {
          "method": "POST",
          "path": "/_snapshot/elasticsearch-snapshots-new/_verify",
          "body": "",
          "querystring": "",
          "headers": {
            "user-agent": "elasticsearch-js/7.16.0-canary.7 (linux 5.15.107+-x64; Node.js v16.13.0)",
            "x-elastic-product-origin": "kibana",
            "x-opaque-id": "57a97e1d-1ac4-4fab-9b27-c69aceea0ecf",
            "authorization": "Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpjaGVpMWV0aDllaWRpZUh1NGlkYWU5SHVi",
            "x-elastic-client-meta": "es=7.16.0p,js=16.13.0,t=7.16.0p,hc=16.13.0"
          },
          "timeout": 30000
        },
        "options": {},
        "id": 1
      },
      "name": "elasticsearch-js",
      "connection": {
        "url": "https://elk-elasticsearch-master:9200/",
        "id": "https://elk-elasticsearch-master:9200/",
        "headers": {},
        "deadCount": 0,
        "resurrectTimeout": 0,
        "_openRequests": 0,
        "status": "alive",
        "roles": {
          "master": true,
          "data": true,
          "ingest": true,
          "ml": false
        }
      },
      "attempts": 0,
      "aborted": false
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to troubleshoot this, but no success yet